# Data Cant Display in Rest API call by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I am using rest API in Javascript, Jquery to gepcoding. in this code i cant get data outside from `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()` function

There is my Code to get data From Google API

```
    var postdata = '{"cellTowers":[{"cellId": '+cid+',"locationAreaCode": '+lac+',"mobileCountryCode": '+mcc+',"mobileNetworkCode": '+mnc+'}]}'
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOURKEY";
    xmlhttp.open('POST',url,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.send(postdata);

    var lat;
    var lng;
    var data = '';
    var json;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
            if (xmlhttp.responseText)
            {
                var data = xmlhttp.responseText;
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                lat = json.location.lat;
                lng = json.location.lng;
                alert(lat+""+lng);        //Working  [1 operation]
            }
      }
 };
 alert(lat+""+lng); //Not Working    [2 operation]
```

in this Code i am trying to get postdata out side  `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()` function and but i get null value. because when i run program i see first [2 operation] operation after then i see [1 operation]

have any problem in my code? or give me suggestion about that problem. or can any different way to use that API

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine. Function runs asynchronous, when event happens. It is normal that 2 operation gets executed before the answer gets back from remote API. Please let me know what makes you unhappy. Code is fine, works as intended, gets the answer from remote API when available. The answer can only be received inside the function, then you should continue calling followup code, as for you app logic from there.

Comment: there are second alert show first, after then first alert show

Comment: after your answer i just change in Question that change local `var lat,lng` to `instance var`

Comment: this will change nothing, as I just said [2 operation], alert stops executions then [1 operation] when it happens.

Comment: is there any solution of that, i get data in [2 operation]?

Comment: no. synchronous ajax is deprecated, and with detrimental effect on UX. What's wrong with the way things are? you do not need [2 operation], just run desired code as a callback in place of [1 operation].

Comment: I had  to try that on loop bt they are work only in last result for that I want to display in [2 operation ]